# Resharper is flagging my Promise as an error

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, resharper

I have the following Typescript code:

```
private getWorkbookFromFile(excelFile: File): Promise<xlsx.IWorkBook> {
    var loadedPromise = new Promise<xlsx.IWorkBook>((resolve, reject) => {
        // stuff to come up with the resolve.
    });

    return loadedPromise;
}
```

Visual studio is turning the word `Promise` red (as an error).  But when I compile and run, it works fine.

I hit my head on the wall for this for a while then decided to turn off Resharper.  Once I did syntax highlighting showed no errors!  (And I can still compile and run.)

I am running Typescript **targeting es6** (es2015).  When you do that, you don't need extra typing (ie `es6-promise`) for Promises.  Visual Studio knows that, but Resharper does not seem to know it.

**So, the question is, how can I get Resharper to realize that my Typescript is targeting es6 (es2015) and that promise is OK?**

I will have to develop without resharper for now, but I like the other things it gives, so I would LOVE a fix for this.

Things I have tried:

• Setting Javascript to ES6 (and Experimental) in the Resharper Options.
• Setting my Compiler Options to be ES6 (I also tried ES2015) in the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: I just had the same issue with Resharper 2018. Upgrading to latest version fixed it for me to. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated to Resharper 2016.2 and this issue was resolved.